# How can I define alias for Mongo Shell

Tags: alias, mongodb-shell

In MongoDB Shell, there is a command `edit <variable>` to inspect/modify the value by your favourite editor specified by EDITOR.

But how can I create an alias for `edit`, such as `e <variable>`?

Answer (score 0):

The `edit` command is part of the C++ implementation of the `mongo` shell ([`src/mongo/shell/dbshell.cpp#L470`](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/v3.4/src/mongo/shell/dbshell.cpp#L470) in the MongoDB GitHub repo). Native functions like `edit` are exposed in the interactive shell interpreter but are not readily available to invoke or override via JavaScript (see: [Differences Between Interactive and Scripted mongo](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/write-scripts-for-the-mongo-shell/#differences-between-interactive-and-scripted-mongo)).

As at MongoDB 3.4 I'm not aware of any obvious way to alias a native code function unless you're keen to modify the source code and build a custom `mongo` shell.

However, if you are writing any significant scripts for the `mongo` shell a much more recommendable approach would be to use the [`load(...)`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/load/) command instead of `edit`.

Advantages of `load()` over `edit` include:

- Ability to edit multiple variables and functions in a single file.

  - `edit` only edits a single variable or function.
- Detect JavaScript syntax errors before you close your draft

  - `edit` detects changes when your editor closes a temporary file; with `load()` you can test successive edits by saving in your editor without closing.
  - If `edit` encounters any JavaScript syntax errors when a file is closed, you'll lose your draft and the variable in the shell will remain at the original value.
- Your working files are saved in a non-temporary path so you can commit them to version control.